# Convert query with exists to joins

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to convert this query in such a way so it does not have any 'exists' and uses only simple joins.

```
select  t.Teacher_id, t.Teacher_name, a.marks, a.grade_ID
from Grades a
left join students s on a.student_ID = s.student_ID
left join Teachers t on t.Teacher_ID = s.Teacher_ID
where 1=1 and t.Teacher_id = 1807600
and   exists(
select p.Payment_ID from payments p 
inner join lookups l on (l.lookup_id = p.status_id and l.lookup_key in ('condition1','condition2'))  
where p.student_ID = a.student_ID
)
```

I tried something like:

```
select  t.Teacher_id, t.Teacher_name, a.marks, a.grade_ID
from Grades a
left join students s on a.student_ID = s.student_ID
left join Teachers t on t.Teacher_ID = s.Teacher_ID
inner join payments p on p.student_ID = a.student_ID
inner join lookups l on (l.lookup_id = p.status_id and l.lookup_key in ('condition1','condition2')) 
where 1=1 and t.Teacher_id = 1807600
```

But I'm not getting the right results. Can you please help. Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with EXISTS()?

Comment: I need to create this query in a tool that doesnot support exists directsly.

Comment: You say you're not getting the right results?  What's wrong with them?  Duplicates by chance?  BTW, you're `outer join` is being negated with `where t.Teacher_id = 1807600`

Comment: If the tool restricts you: it is not a tool, but a handicap. throw away the tool.

Comment: @sgeddes: that's correct. I'm getting duplicates. Where can I give this condition then?

Comment: While I prefer using `exists` for this, if it's not possible, then you are seeing one of the main differences with `exists` and `join`.  You need to add `distinct` to your `select` statement to remove the duplicates.  When you `join` to the other tables, if they have more than 1 row that matches, that's why you're receiving duplicates.

Comment: @sgeddes: It works if I use distinct but the problem is I'm trying to construct this query using just joins (not using custom Query) in tableau and it will not let me pick distinct anywhere. So was trying to see if this can be done in a way that will satisfy my need.Thanks

Comment: Can you use `GROUP BY`? `DISTINCT` is the same as using `GROUP BY` with all the columns in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Can you join with a subquery?

Comment: And there is also the (COUNT (*) FROM correlated_subquery) > 0

Comment: @Barmar: In my case I can't use 'distinct' or 'group by'.  May be I can try subquery and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could use group by, but this restricts the maintainability of the script for the simple sake of not using EXISTS().

```
select  t.Teacher_id, t.Teacher_name, a.marks, a.grade_ID
from Grades a
left join students s on a.student_ID = s.student_ID
left join Teachers t on t.Teacher_ID = s.Teacher_ID
inner join payments p on p.student_ID = a.student_ID
inner join lookups l on (l.lookup_id = p.status_id and l.lookup_key in ('condition1','condition2')) 
where t.Teacher_id = 1807600
group by  t.Teacher_id, t.Teacher_name, a.marks, a.grade_ID
```